# How to associate a file with an app using "Commander One" on macOS Monterey

Tags: finder, file

I'm trying to associate video files with VLC.
I use "Commander One" as file explorer and I used to be able to do that through the **Get Info** dialog or the **Open With** option in "Commander One".
Neither works, I'm using Monterey.

- In the **Open With** dialog (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+click on file), I can see the dialog but I do not have the option to make this permanent for all files. There used to be an option like "do it for all files" or something.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Open With' dialog box without the option to choose a different application]

- In the **Get Info** dialog, there was a section about file association: "open with" with a bunch of options. It's not present on my Mac.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Get Info' window for an .avi with no 'Open With' option]

Don't know what's going on here, looks like my OS is broken.

Comment: The file is in /Movies so not your own home directory - who owns the file and directory? I thought this was shown in Sharing and Permissions

Comment: My user is the owner of the file. Yes, the file is on a different disk partition for Data that is not user specific. Why should it matter where the file is for OSX to show the options?

Comment: That looks like a non-standard Finder Get Info panel. Sharing and Permissions is not normally checkboxes, and doesn't have the unix number. I'm on Ventura and Sonoma, but Get Info doesn't look like it has changed for decades. You should still see an Open With control.

Comment: Which exact version of OSX are you using - that panel looks like a very old version (my earlier question was because a different user might explain the issue), Can you also show the owner of the file if not via Finder then by Terminal and ls -l

Comment: I'm using Monterey (it's in the title) - I can confirm the owner is my user.

Comment: Ok, found the issue thanks to both of you. I use "Commander One" as file explorer. It used to show the OS "get info"  or "open with" dialogs. Now it still does, but it looks like it's showing different dialogs. Either older versions, or with limited options. Not sure what API's it's calling, there is no way to tell that it's doing something different.

Comment: It's drawing it's own Get Info dialog.  Forklift does this too.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it turns out that Commander One is displaying its own file info dialog. Although the menu looks like it will use the OS one.

There is no solution to this other than using Finder.